# how to parse an input value thats hidden

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I can't find anything on here or google related to parsing input values that are hidden. For example this piece of code here. I am trying to parse the 40 character key.

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="c126b4f134cb2c1184c1585fdfa4d1b0013a12f4">
```

i tried this but it never returns the value of anything hidden.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=524970&boxtag=7xpsk7&sec=form');
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $nodes = $xp->query('//input/@value');
    foreach($nodes as $node)
        {
          echo( $node->textContent . "<br><br>" );
        }

var_dump($node);
```

update code

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=524970&boxtag=7xpsk7&sec=form');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//input[type="hidden"]');
$val = $nodes->getAttribute('value');

var_dump($val);
```

returns this error referring to line "$val = $nodes->getAttribute('value');"

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()
```

Comment: XPath returns a NODEList as its result, not a node. Try `$nodes[0]->getAttribute()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$nodes = $xp->query('//input[type="hidden"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $val = $node->getAttribute('value');
}
```

---

comment followup:

If you look at the source of the page you've included in your code sample, you'll see there's only a single hidden form field, and it's got an empty value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="">
```

so of course the XPath will return a NULL - that's what's stored in that value attribute: nothing.

Comment: @jennifer: The only hidden field in that page is `<input type="hidden" name="key" value="">`. So maybe that's why you get no result. Also the `->textContent` from your question would be empty in either case(?)

Comment: @mario yes the for each loop is not necessary since there is only one instance of that code like you said, but how would i obtain that string from value?

Comment: @jennifer: I bet 15¢ that you didn't use `->getAttribute("value")` like Marc`s example said.

Comment: @mario i update my post to reflect my current script and i get "Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()"

Comment: You're probably doing `$nodes->getAttribute()` (note the S on node). Use `$node` instead. $nodes is a NODEList as returned by the XPath query. $node is a single node from that list.

Comment: @Marc B i get this error "Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array" $nodes[0]->getAttribute()

Comment: Woops. brainfart, sorry. should be `$nodes->item(0)->getAttribute(...)`

Comment: @Marc B I figured out the issue. I tried to use curl and file_get_content and then var_dump the variable to vew teh source and the value="" is always empty. The value is being generated by  http://www.cbox.ws/box/jsc.php?v=660 so i assume thats why its empty. do you know how i could obtain the value if its being generated that way?

Comment: If the page isn't outputting the value, then you'll have to get it by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

Using your update code, the fixed version would be:

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// This link is now dead...
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=524970&boxtag=7xpsk7&sec=form');
libxml_clear_errors();

$val = array(); // Must be set before foreach loop

$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//input[type="hidden"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $val[] = $node->getAttribute('value');
}

var_dump($val);

?>
```